# I am getting error in IPv6 socket connection

Tags: c, tcp, ipv6

My server is creating a IPV6 socket.

On client I am creating a IPV4 socket. 
Now, In the connect API on client side I am passing the socket descriptor of IPV4 and IPV6 address structure.

```
INET_connect( sock,(SocketAddress *)in6_addr,(int)sizeof( sockaddr_in6 ) ) == 0 )
```

where

```
struct sockaddr_in6 in6_addr;
```

I am getting error in connection. Is it due to this or some other reason ?
Please note that my server is IPV6(having an IPV6 address)

Comment: Sounds like you have just ‘decided’ to use IPv6 without actually understanding what it is, and what will or won’t work.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. So nice of you to enlighten me.Anyways, I was just wondering that if I create a socket with IPV4 and convert the address passed as IPV6 format into IPV4 format then the connection might be established. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you might be wrong because you don't show the code of how you convert and you haven't described the platform that you are using. Modern OSes would allow your IPv4 client to talk to IPv6 server (server would see an IP4-mapped IP6 address). If you edit your question with the necessary details, SO will probably be more helpful to you.

Comment: voting up, as this question might be useful in highlighting some kind of common (or not so common) misunderstanding

Comment: 'I am getting error in connection' is not a problem description. You need to post the *actual* error message. Also a system call returning zero is not evidence of an error, it is evidence of success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use an IPV6 socket to connect to an IPV6 address, or use a tunneling service which will translate traffic from IPV4 addresses to and from IPV6 addresses.

Comment: @Edwin...Can you suggest how to tunnel IPV6 address to IPV4 address. I guess this can solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: http://www.networkworld.com/news/2010/050610-ipv6-tunnel-basics.html is a good introductory start.  It sounds like you need to evaluate what will work / is available for your environment.

Answer (score 3):

> On client I am creating a IPV4 socket

Why? Don't do that. If your client program creates an AF_INET socket (or is running on ip4-only OS) then there is nothing you can do **on the client side** to make such connection happen.

If you just have to do so - then it is the server that should be adapted to handle IPv4 clients.

Server might be able to accept a connection request from ip4 client - but it can only happen if *server side* disables IPV6_V6ONLY socket option and, obviously, if server's OS allows that. In this case ip6 server will see the ip4 client via ipv4-mapped ipv6  address.